How does וְ / הֶאֱמִן vᵊhe'ĕmin "believe" reflect the root word אָמַן 'āman?
The Hebrew word for "believe" is וְ / הֶאֱמִן vᵊhe'ĕmin. As in Genesis 15:6:
"Then he believed in the Lord; and He reckoned it to him as righteousness."
The root for וְ / הֶאֱמִן vᵊhe'ĕmin, is אָמַן
'āman, which means to stay, to sustain, to support; To be firm, unshaken.
So when the verb is used, וְ / הֶאֱמִן vᵊhe'ĕmin i.e. "believe", how does this reflect the root meaning? Does it mean that the person believing is firm and unshakeable in their belief, or does it mean that the object of their belief is firm and unshakeable?

First, the verb used in Gen 15:6 is אָמַן (aman) which has the fundamental meaning, "to confirm, support".  It is a fundamental root word in Hebrew.  A better translation is "trust" rather than "believe".
This can be confirmed by the NT's frequent instruction to "stand firm in the faith" such as:

1 Cor 16:13 - Be on guard. Stand firm in the faith. Be courageous. Be
strong.
2 Cor 1:24 - Not that we lord it over your faith, but we are fellow
workers with you for your joy, because it is by faith that you stand
firm.
1 Peter 5:12 - Resist him, standing firm in your faith and in the
knowledge that your brothers throughout the world are undergoing the
same kinds of suffering.

There are many more such as: 2 Thess 2:15, Gal 5:1, 1 Thess 3:8, Eph 6:11, 14, 1 Cor 10:12, 15:58, Col 1:23, 4:12, John 8:44, 2 Peter 1:12, Matt 24:13, etc.

I also prefer the word, TRUST. It's simple, strong, and clear in English, whereas the word, faith, somehow feels mystical and unachievable, involving candles, dark fragrances, and stained-glass windows. But that's just me. ;-)

@Dieter - strongly agree

Thank you @Dottard. So out of the two possibilities of "believe" meaning the believer is firm and unshakeable, or that the object of their belief is firm and unshakeable, you would choose the former?
Researching earlier today, I see there is a case to be made for the latter, as well. Because apparently in Genesis 15:6 the form used is "Hiphil" (I'm new to these terms) and takes on declarative sense: "to consider something reliable or dependable.
What are your thoughts?

@Luke -in the case of the Christian's faith/trust - we have an anchor, firm and secure in the rock of Jesus Christ.  See Heb 6:19, 20.
